# Accessでラベルに複数の名前を出力するには？

Tags: sql, ms-access

MS-Accessご教示ください．

やりたいことは、ハガキの宛名シールの作成です．シールは市販のA4サイズで3列×6行分印刷可能です．

すでに作成元のDBはあって対象者を抽出できています．
最終的に出力するフィールドは以下の通りです．

post-no（リテラル）
adrs（住所）
name（名前＋"様"）

ところが、一軒に複数の対象者がある場合（例えば世帯の夫婦の両方を対象にしたい場合）、nameを「～様」として改行、更に続けて「～様」としたいとの要望が出て苦慮しています．

post-no, adrsまでは集計クェリーでグルーピングしていますが、明細（name）はどのようにして1枚のラベルに出力するようにできますでしょうか？

良い方法がありましたら教えていただければ幸いです．

以上

Comment: 複数のレコードが同じ世帯の住人(夫婦、家族など)であるという判断は何でするのですか？　同じ住所だけれど、同姓の親、叔父夫婦が同居している場合は、本人、親、叔父夫婦の３通に分けないと失礼になるのではないですか？

Comment: はい、御指摘のとおりです．元データに世帯コードのようなものを持っていてこれでグルーピングして、同じ世帯の住人と判断します．一世帯の中には世帯主に該当するフラグを持っています．ただそれ以上の情報はありませんので、家族構成を分けて別々にすることはいたしません．

Comment: 世帯コードが同じデータを集めて、その中で世帯主フラグを持つデータのnameを最初に印刷し、残った世帯主フラグを持たないデータのnameを順に印刷すれば良いように思いますが、それではダメなのでしょうか？　nameに名前のリストをカンマ区切り文字列で入れるようにすれば、カンマを改行に変えたものを印刷することで複数の名前を出すことができるかと思います。　「何がしたいのか」という事と「現在のDBの構成にした思想」にずれが生じているような感じを受けます。

Comment: 元のDBの構成は一人別です．例えれば「市ー区ー常会ー世帯ー個人の名称、性別、生年月日などの個人別情報」．ハガキの宛名シールは、このDBで行う一つの業務処理の一つに過ぎません．一般に宛名シールはDBから抽出した一行でしか明細部分が作れません．抽出の際、世帯でグルーピングはできるので、複数の名前を明細に落とし込めないか？というのが質問です．